# how to unpack-objects to stdout?

Tags: git

I'm trying to unpack a git object but the issue is that it's being unpacked in the .git directory. I would need it unpacked into stdout so that I can futher process it.

`cat test_pack_no_header | git unpack-objects --stdout`

I get:

`usage: git unpack-objects [-n] [-q] [-r] [--strict]`

Maybe I don't understand how this is supposed to work but from the docs to me it seems --stdout is an option (amonth many others than -n -q -r)

```
--stdout  Write the pack contents (what would have been written to .pack      
 file) out to the standard output.
```

Full usage:

```
git pack-objects [-q | --progress | --all-progress] [--all-progress-implied]
               [--no-reuse-delta] [--delta-base-offset] [--non-empty]
               [--local] [--incremental] [--window=<n>] [--depth=<n>]
               [--revs [--unpacked | --all]] [--stdout | base-name]
               [--keep-true-parents] < object-list
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What do you want to achieve at the end? Sound a lot like some kind of [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @michas I need to unpack the object so that I can read it in a program without to create a git repository. It's useful when you don't have file access. Does it make sense?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, a git object isn't only a file, it can also be a directory tree or a commit, you need t have at least a git repo to organise them for you, or you need to parse the pack files manually

Comment: As far as I understand the unpacked objects are actually compressed using zlib. I'm interested in an object only (a tag object) so I'm certain the unpacket object has only one "item". Nevertheless if what I need is not possible I'm wondering what is the ``--stdout`` flag for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pack-objects` writes to stdout and reads objects from the repo.

`git unpack-objects` reads from stdin and writes objects to the repo.

This allows taking objects from a repo transfering them and unpacking them to another repo.

Just unpack to an empty repo and process the resulting objects there.

Comment: I can see that but then what is the --stdout flag for? The issue is (as I mentioned above) that I don't have access to the file system.

Comment: Only pack has an stdout flag. Unpack will create many files. Therefore stdout would not make much sense.

Comment: you are right... sorry for my erroneous question. I trusted google too much as on "git unpack-objects to stdout it lists git-pack so I just picked-up the wrong doc. Long story short it seems that what I need(unpack objects on the fly) is not possible with git.